# css - arabic charecter is wrong when using custom font in ie11

Tags: html, css

I'm using a custom:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BYekan";
    src: url(fonts/Yekan.eot);
    src: url(fonts/Yekan.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(fonts/Yekan.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/Yekan.ttf) format("truetype"), url(fonts/Yekan.svg#BYekan) format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
body,*{
    font-family:BYekan,"BYekan",tahoma,Arial !important;

}
```

It works fine in every browser but in IE 11. It's very bad and it's not readable at all.

I want to use system default fonts, if user agent browser is IE 11.

How can I use another font when a user enters my website with IE 11?

Thanks.

Comment: Mohamad, have you been able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_IE.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_not_IE.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in `css_IE.css` use systen default fonts and in `css_not_IE.css` use your custom fonts